# day function in lubridate package R

Tags: r, date, lubridate

I read description of `day` function in `lubridate` package and am trying to understand how it works. Here is my example:

```
library(lubridate)
test_date <- as.POSIXct('2017-02-28')
day(test_date) <-1
```

now `test_date` contains "2017-01-31 18:00:00 CST", while I would expect it to have '2017-02-01'

Could anybody clarify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

R date-times are stored as UTC( aka GMT, aka UCT) times. When as.POSIXct is given only a date value it automatically assumes midnight. Your result is displaying '2017-02-01' at midnight in Greenwich, England as the time in your local time zone (probably US Eastern Standard Time).  I actually cannot reproduce this behavior on my Mac. I get:

```
> day(test_date) <- 1
> test_date
[1] "2017-02-01 PST"
```

Different OSes may handle their timezone conventions differently. The help page to start with is:

```
?DateTimeClasses
```

> Some Unix-like systems (especially Linux ones) do not have environment variable TZ set, yet have internal code that expects it (as does POSIX). We have tried to work around this, but if you get unexpected results try setting TZ. See ?Sys.timezone for valid settings.